# Log in system in c# with access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to create log in system with access database in c#.
I have a database, and User_ID and Password Columns, I don't know why it doesn't work, can you help me with your opinion?
The problem is that program checks only 1st user, but when I enter 3rd or 4th user, it displays message: your username or password is incorrect even though user_ID and password is correct.
here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Hodzic\Desktop\projekat shipping\Database files\Users.accdb";
        connect.Open();


        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "select User_ID, Password from user_details";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

                if (textBox1.Text == reader[0].ToString() && textBox2.Text == reader[1].ToString())
                {


                    this.Hide();
                    Glavna2 g1 = new Glavna2();
                    g1.Show();
                    break;

                }

                else 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your user ID or password is incorrect.");
                    this.Hide();
                    Sign_in g2 = new Sign_in();
                    g2.Show();
                    break;
                }


        }

        connect.Close();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a WHERE clause here:

```
command.CommandText = "select User_ID, Password from user_details";
```

Currently you're just checking the first result of the reader, so if you're going to do that (which is fine), you need a WHERE clause.

Something like:

```
command.CommandText = "select User_ID, Password from user_details WHERE User_ID = 'myusername'";
```

Clearly, you'll need to concatenate that, and many would argue that you'll need to worry about SQL injection (so that would imply a prepared statement), but let's start there and then we can move on.

Additionally, as SLaks stated, you don't want to store the passwords in plain text. So, there is quite a bit of tweaking needed for your application, but getting data back will be a start.

Next research:

- Prepared statements in Microsoft Access.
- Password hashing.

Comment: I understand what you have told me but i don't know how to do that because I am new in this. My problem is that my professor for programming doesn't know anything literally, he gave me a project,to make something like ebay with ms access database because we didn't learn sql and all i do is surfing the internet, trying to find some solutions and 90% of my time in coding, i am fixing the code.if i ask him to help me, he says i cant, you do it by yourself. (he doesn't know eihter) sorry on spam. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @VlasicVilaPanda, like I stated, modify the query you've got first and get data coming back. That's step one. And then start Googling for the rest.